# Scroll div instead of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, lightbox

I have a lightbox of sorts on a website I am working on which acts like a "View Source" button. The background goes dark and the source appears but will only scroll if you have your mouse over that particular `div` (or in this case `pre`). I want to able to, for example, have my mouse in the top corner of the page and scroll down and I want the main lightbox to scroll. There's loads of code so I've used:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

I'm sure it will require some JavaScript or jQuery, but I've no idea where to being.

It's in oporation on [this page](http://css3framework.co.uk/) when you scroll down and click 'View Full Code'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most straight-forward way would be: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Ezvnp/3/.

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) { // on scroll
    var $div = $('div');

    // set div scroll top offset to current + extra from this scroll
    $div.scrollTop($div.scrollTop() 
                    - e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);

    return false; // prevent body scrolling
});
```

To lock/unlock the scrolling, you could use a variable so as to only lock when that variable is `true`, e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Ezvnp/4/.

```
var locked = true;

$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(locked) {
        var $div = $('div');

        $div.scrollTop($div.scrollTop() 
                        - e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);

        return false;
    }
});

$('button').click(function() {
    locked = !locked;
});
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks!

Is this the best way to restore back to normal?

  $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
   $('body').scrollTop($('body').scrollTop()
                   - e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
   return false;
  });

Comment: @Edd Turtle: Personally, I wouldn't say so. Just don't do anything and it will use the normal behaviour. See my edit please.

Comment: @Edd Turtle: I see you have blent the code nicely into your webpage. Though, I forgot to mention that you should *not* bind it every time. It now adds the function each time you open the code, so when opening the code box twice, the scrolling is twice as fast. Instead, you might want to bind the function only once at page load, and only change `locked` on click. Also, instead of `locked = !locked`, you might want to disable it with `locked = false`.

Comment: Great, didn't notice that, makes much more sense now :) A shame that I restored the website to an earlier version by accident... arrgh

Comment: This works perfectly (still) in Chrome, but unfortunately does not seem to work in Firefox. Any suggestions on how to make this work would be very much appreciated!