# Javascript - Scrolling the div instead of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to set up a page where, if the mouse is over the div, only the div scrolls, but if the mouse is over the page, the page scrolls.

Below is a similar answer:
[Scroll div instead of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349848/scroll-div-instead-of-page) with a jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Ezvnp/4/

However, this "lock" button stops the page from scrolling whilst it is locked. I want the page to be scrollable at the same time as the div, but such that hitting the bottom/top of the div doesn't start scrolling the page (if that makes sense).

Any idea how this would be done please? I currently have the same code as seen in the jsfddle.

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(locked) {
        var $div = $('div');

        $div.scrollTop($div.scrollTop() 
                        - e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Ezvnp/104/

Use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events to check for mouse within div. They can do the same thing as the button was doing previously, switching the state of locked.

They are basically event listeners that get triggered when the mouse enters and leaves the element, and you have to check for both of them to toggle the state.

I'm not sure if event listeners are even necessary, when I deleted all the javascript it still worked just the way you want, it might just be a browser thing but try commenting out all the javascript, and if it works I can update my answer to just this part to make it more helpful.

Comment: Which browser was you using? The mouseenter/mouseleave works brilliantly though, thank you. Will test it on the major browsers.

Comment: Looks like FireFox works out of the box, but Chrome, Safari and IE don't.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is no need for any JavaScript at all? The browser treats the scrolling div in the way you want by default, look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezvnp/105/). `have to add code to post jsfiddle link :P`

Comment: That's now how I want it though, I am asking if it's possible that whilst the mouse is in the div, reaching the bottom of the div does NOT scroll the webpage.